# How does object spread notation transform react redux props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, redux, react-redux

Looking at the react-redux [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html), I'm confused on how the object spread notation transforms an object to become props. On the example below:

```
const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map(todo =>
      <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo}
        onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
)
```

how does the `{...todo}` get transformed to work inside-

```
const Todo = ({ onClick, completed, text }) => (
  <li
    onClick={onClick}
    style={{
      textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'
    }}
  >
    {text}
  </li>
)
```

I know the `{...todo}` returns an object that has keys completed, text, and id. But how does that get extracted out to fit into the `const Todo` function? Are the arguments that get passed into this function always going to correspond exactly to the props that get passed in from TodoList?

Comment: It's not really an object spread operator as far as Javascript is concerned, it's a React concept that just looks very similar. It would have to look like `{{...todo}}` to be interpreted as an ES6 object spread operator.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, consider:

```js
const MyParentComponent =  () => {
  const bar = { a: 'Hello', b: 'world' }

  return <MyChildComponent foo={ '!' } {...bar} />
}


const MyChildComponent = ({ a, b, foo }) => (
  <div>{ `${a} ${b}${foo}` }</div>
)
```

Thanks to the spread notation, `bar`'s keys (`a` and `b`) are extracted and passed as props to the child component.

Which is different from [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```
const MyParentComponent =  () => (
  <MyChildComponent a={ 'Hello' } b={ 'world' } foo={ '!' } />
)


const MyChildComponent = ({ a, b, ...bar }) => ({
  <div>{ `${a} ${b}${bar.foo}` }</div>
})
```

Notice that in this case `bar` is an object containing all the extra keys that are not [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).